# Symbols instead of numbers on first row of keaboard?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, configuration, keyboard-layout

I program a lot and it bothers me that numbers are default, not the symbols on the front row.
I would like to try the other way (And, no, I don't want to switch to Dvorak).
How to configure Emacs (or whole Ubuntu) to do just that?

Please note that I don't want to mess existing shortcuts I use like CTRL+1 etc.

Comment: Not programming related, so voting to close as "off topic".

Comment: Perhaps rather than just closing it could move to SuperUser but actually to my eye this is programming related- how many non-programmers are going to want to have a symbol lock running in Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

```
 ; Keyboard Remapping
 (global-set-key (kbd "1") "!")
```